# How do I print via email without explaining it to a multitude of users in a course of a month

Tags: email, printing

Right now, If one wants to print, he needs to have the email address of the printer, but, if there are a lot of users coming and going, which is the case, distributing that email address, a hundred+- times a month, can be a bit tiring.

So, I ask: How do I print via email without explaining it to a multitude of users in a course of a month

Comment: Whatever you do, aren't you going to have to tell users *how* to print? Why is giving them the email address of the printer at this stage not an option? Why is it worse than something else?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, had a misunderstanding with my co-worker. What fabby suggested, is the solution.

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention "HP" in your tags: [e-mail printing](https://www.hp.com/go/eprintcenter) is a functionality of some of the newer (and not so new) HP printers which allow you to bypass having to set up printing for visitors.

So instead of having to support visitors who know nothing abouts CUPS, Drivers, USB cables, WiFi/cable networks and such, **you just have to stick a label on the printer telling visitors to e-mail anything to that e-mail address and it'll *magically* print everything *including attachments*!  ;-)**

Bonus points if you include unicorns and rainbows on the label!